# Cypher query to find difference between sets of related nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using Neo4J to store test results from some nightly automated testing.  I have nodes that represent tests that can be run (:Test), nodes that represent runs of a set of tests (:Run).  Each (:Run) has relationships to the existing (:Test) nodes to indicate a "PASS" or "FAIL", i.e.:

http://console.neo4j.org/?id=9hj4w4

I was hoping to be able to construct a cypher query that could look at two (:Run) nodes and return the differences between them -- specifically determine the (:Test) nodes that are different between them, and indicate the relationship (PASS/FAIL) for those differences.

I know it can be done outside of Neo4J, but I was hoping to find a solution that does as much of the work as possible within Neo4J.

Comment: Your example data doesn't have any instances where there are tests that have different outcomes. Is this intended?

Comment: Oops - you're right.  Not intended.  For a variety of reasons, I kept having to recreate my example and it seems the last version had too many cut & pastes.  I had intended for at least one of the results to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you're interested in test differences between Run1 and Run2. You can do:

```
MATCH (a:Run)-[x]->(t:Test)<-[y]-(b:Run)
WHERE a.name = "Run1" AND b.name = "Run2" AND TYPE(x) <> TYPE(y)
RETURN a.name, TYPE(x), t.name, TYPE(y), b.name
ORDER BY t.name;
```

Unfortunately your example data doesn't have any instances (between any two runs) where there are different outcomes for the same test. I've made a new example dataset so that we actually get results: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=wlx859

Comment: Your query would not return cases where one run is not connected to a test at all, right? Only if both are connected.

Comment: @MartinPreusse Yes. But that doesn't seem to be what OP asked for. Only for differences in pass / fail.

Comment: Maybe. I thought about this for a while and didn't come up with a nice way to get those results as well. Just curiosity though.

Answer (score 0):

try this on for size.
basically match the path for each test and optionally to the same test from another run, then compare the types of relationships ( pass vs fail in this case )   and output the tests that differ.

here is a link to the console [borrowed the data from Nicole](http://console.neo4j.org/r/5z6rmq)

```
MATCH p1 =(a1:Run { name:'Run2' })-[r1]->(t1:Test)
OPTIONAL MATCH p2=(a2:Run { name:'Run1' })-[r2]-(t1)
WITH type(head(relationships(p1))) AS lbl1,type(head(relationships(p2))) AS lbl2, t1
WHERE lbl2 IS NULL OR  lbl1 <> lbl2
RETURN 'Test result mismatched on test: ' + t1.name
```

one note though. the results differ when you ask the revers of run1 vs run2  and run2 vs run1 )  in the case where the latter has more tests